# Reactjs datepicker Select date don't work when I have a other input field behind the calendar

Tags: reactjs, datepicker

Date picker work perfectly with keyboard,
If I use the mouse, it's not working in my red area (screen my screenshot)
I used this one : 
https://github.com/Hacker0x01

See the screen below :
The bleu area works, the date is set well, probably because behind I have the toolbar instead of an input
but if I click on the red part, the value is not set and it focus my draftJs editor behind.

[image]

Comment: can you share a codepen?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into zIndex? If that doesn't work try disabling the textbox when the date picker is open.

Comment: I tried both, and it's not working. Event change the editor to readonly...